# Oversized icons and text, text not completely displayed

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image]

iPhone has standard and not zoom mode enabled, yet the text and icons have a larger font.

The favorite, flag, share and edit options only show icons and their text(function) isn’t displayed.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone10,2)
- OS Version: Version 13.6 (Build 17G68)